# How to write name of a member along with name of its containing group?

Tags: sentence-construction

Suppose we have three different groups: A, B and C. Now, my question would be how should we say A:

> "group A" or "A group"

For making it more clear, consider a situation in which we would want recommend a group to an individual. Which one of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> You should use group A.
>
> You should use A group.

---

**UPDATE #1:**

As @Victor Bazarov kindly has commented, in this case A and B could placeholders for longer phrases. For example:

> You should consume tropical fruits group.
>
> You should consume group tropical fruits.

Comment: *group* at first place looks far natural. I follow World Cups and there it is always 'Group A' and not 'A Group'.

Comment: @MaulikV: In World Cups the group names are *literally* 'A', 'B' etc.  Here they can be placeholders, and the real names can be adjectives or numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither option sounds quite right unless you have groups **named** "A", "B" and "C".

When "A", "B" and "C" are being used as nouns (as is common in the Football World Cup), then favour "group" at the start.

> England, Brazil, Spain and France from Group A will continue to the next round.

---

I've had to think about the word group, but I think the pattern is: If you are using group with an adjective, put the adjective in front. If you are using it with a noun, put the word group in front and add "of"

> I joined my local gymnastics group.
>
> I have joined a group of gymnasts.

---

For your example specifically, you should consider something like:

> You should consume [more] from the tropical fruits **food group**.

Here, the world **food group** is a compound noun. I'm not sure it works perfectly as "tropical fruits" isn't one of the standard [food groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_group).

---

> Suppose we've got a function called showMessage then which one do you use? "You should use showMessage function." or "You should use function showMessage."

Here I would use the first option, but add a definite article.

> You should use **the** `showMessage` function.

---

> I saw in many cases that people say: "Variable x is used for ..." so, why wouldn't we say "x variable is used for ..."?

I can't think of the rule here, but `Variable x` is the correct way to say this. You **can** omit the word variable completely:

> The `tutorialMetadata` variable is used to store information read from an XML file.
>
> `tutorialMetadata` is used to store information read from an XML file.

Comment: I just checked out your profile and saw you're a programmer, just like me. So, how do you say name of a method/function in a programming language? Suppose we've got a function called `showMessage` then which one do you use? "You should use showMessage function." or "You should use function showMessage." Thanks James!

Comment: I've added to my answer @abforce

Comment: Thanks James for that. However I still have another question. I saw in many cases that people say: "Variable x is used for ..." so, why wouldn't we say "x variable is used for ..."?

Comment: @abforce As a native speaker, I can tell you intuitively that "variable *x*" parses much differently in my mind than the tropical fruits example. I need to think about it a bit more so don't take this to the bank, but I suspect we're treating it a bit like a title + name as a proper noun, e.g. President Obama.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive `title + name` is an interesting point you've mentioned. Thanks. I actually love _native_ speakers `:)`.

Comment: First, I should make clear, "variable *x*" isn't really a proper name and wouldn't take a capital letter. I'm just considering how my brain parses it. 

Second, "the variable (or function) ```showMessage```" sounds much more natural with the definite article. And it's fine to say "The variable ```x```."

Comment: Third, I think there's something special about the short names X, Y, Z here. (Note *Brand X* which Oxford defines as "A name used for an unidentified brand contrasted unfavorably with a product of the same type being promoted," although it's also used to mean generic or commodity, i.e. no particular brand at all.) Suppose Person X goes to City Y on Airline Z.... all of these are much different than saying "the variable ```x```, i.e. the variable whose name is literally *x*.

In conclusion, I'd just treat _____ X as a set phrase, not to be generalized. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can either say "tropical fruit group" or "the group of tropical fruit" according to the Oxford Collocations Dictionary.

Comment: While this may be correct, it's not very helpful without more elaboration.

Comment: Moreover, without some specific context, these both sound unnatural at best.